# Ayuda codigo de C en Geany

Tags: estructuras-de-datos, nodos

disculpen la molestia me podrian ayudar con un problema de compilacion que tengo, el siguiente codigo lo compile y funcionó, luego cerre todos los codigos abiertos en el IDE que uso (Geany) y al momento de compilar de nuevo me da error, y no se porque, me da estos errores al momento de compilar:

```
RevertirFrase.c:15:26: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before '&' token
RevertirFrase.c:44:4: warning: implicit declaration of function 'add' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <time.h>
struct reverse
{
    char letra;
    struct reverse *sig;
};
void add(struct reverse *&pila,int letra)
{
struct reverse *nuevoNodo=(struct reverse*)malloc(sizeof(struct reverse));
nuevoNodo->letra=letra;
nuevoNodo->sig=pila;
pila=nuevoNodo;
}
void show(struct reverse *letra)
{
struct reverse *ptr=NULL;
ptr=letra;
while(ptr!=NULL)
{
    printf("%c",ptr->letra);
    ptr=ptr->sig;
}
}
int main()
{
int esc;
printf("Ingresa la frase: \nPara finalizar pulsa ESC:\n");
struct reverse *nodo=NULL;
do{
    fflush(stdin);
    esc=getch();
    printf("%c",esc);
    if(esc!=27)
        add(nodo,esc);
}while(esc!=27);
show(nodo);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Reemplaza el `struct reverse *&pila` por `struct reverse * pila`. El ampersand está innecesario y en C no se permite ese tipo de sintaxis. En C++ te funcionaría, pero eliminando el * y dejando únicamente el ampersand.

Comment: Gracias, intente compilar sin el ampersand pero creo que no guardaba los valores porque no me mostraba nada, para solucionarlo lo que hice fue declarar asi una la funcion:                       
      struct reverse* add(struct reverse *pila,int letra)